# How to softfail when a log server is unavailable?

Tags: nginx

One of my configuration files includes information about logging:

```
server {
    error_log syslog:server=elk.example.com:513;
    access_log syslog:server=elk.example.com:513;
}
```

If `elk.example.com` is down when the server starts, the start is aborted with

```
Dec 13 08:40:08 nginx nginx[62]: nginx: [emerg] host not found in syslog server "elk.example.com:513" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/logging.conf:3
Dec 13 08:40:08 nginx nginx[62]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

[The documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/monitoring/logging/#logging-to-syslog) does not mention softfail (= going on even if the error occurred) - is such a functionality available?

Comment: Could you syslog to the local machine and specify the remote machine in syslog.conf?

Comment: @RichardSmith: yes, this is my fallback solution. I was hoping to send the logs directly from nginx (for several reasons, some better, some worse), .

Comment: nginx is a great web server, but a terrible log shipper. I would go directly to local logging paired with something that is designed to ship logs.